# Accessing different datasources

Tags: c#, sql, import, odbc

In my data import application I want to allow the user to import data from as much different data sources as possible.

So what is the best way and what are the classes needed to be able to connect to different data sources and then get data from them via SQL queries?

E.g.

```
// 1. A class I need to allow the user to select the needed data source
ConnectionDialog dlg = new ConnectionDialog();
dlg.ShowDialog();

// 2. A class I need to access the data source using the connection string built above
DataConnection con = new DataConnection(dlg.builtConnectionString);
con.doStuff("SELECT * FROM test");
```

Currently I'm using the Microsoft connection dialog (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection) for the first part. But I can't figure out how to use the connection strings returned by it. An OdbcConnection won't accept it (only tested with an Micrsosoft SQL connection string generated by the dialog). Is it even possible to achieve the above or will I be forced to use different classes for the second part?

Edit: I also want the user to be able to install his own drivers for data sources. I just don't know if ODBC or OleDB or anything else is the way to go and if/how I can use the connection dialog with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapping to list of DB sources. Add a connection strings to web.config for each type of DB connection (MSSQL , MYSQL and Oracle) with {{name}} string and then replace this string with the catalog selected by the user.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="mssql" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog={{name}};Integrated Security=True" />
    <add name="mysql" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root; password=PASS;database={{name}};pooling=false" />
    <add name="oracle" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source={{name}};User Id=root;Password=PASS;" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

Now use SqlConnection and MySqlConnection and OracleConnection classes . (You will need mysqlconnector and oracleconnector for these classes).

Comment: I would like the user to be able to install his own drivers (like ODBC). Also i would need multiple classes for the second part.